# Strange HtmlHelper behavior when passing a filtered list model to the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What I'm trying to do is create a form for users to input a username for each company, which will be pulled from the database.  Once the user presses "Create", it will try to add the username to the database.  If there were any companies with usernames with errors (i.e. username too short, contains digits, etc.), I generate the form again with only these companies with blank username fields.  However, this is not working for some reason...

**.NET Fiddle code:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/lAttUb

If you put in the following:

- *delta* for Delta Inc. (Should be accepted)
- *ec* for Ellesmore Centre (Error - too short)
- *430* for 430 Corporation (Error - contains digits)

it will return the form that has *delta* filled in for Ellesmore Centre, and *ec* filled in for 430 Corporation.  From the debugger, it looks like it works up until the HtmlHelper.TextBoxFor methods.  Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you! Have any ideas on the problem?

Comment: The fiddle is kind've hard to navigate (small screens) but it appears to be an ordering problem. Your For loop is gonna run down the records sequentially however they appear in the list. So I bet `Model.WifiAccounts` is ordered differently in your get and post Index methods. Before you pass the list to the view, order it

Comment: I actually post the name of the company along with the username, so it shouldn't be an ordering issue. When I debug the View in VS2013, the Model is formed correctly (the username is "" and with the right companies), but when the page renders I get something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your DisplayFor and TextBoxFor are not in sync

Place a breakpoint on your For Loop and run your test case you described above. 
Your going to find that

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.WifiAccounts[0].CompanyName) == EllesMore Center
```

while

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.WifiAccounts[0].Username) == "Delta"
```

**Edit:**

NVM the above wasn't the case, instead
your View was retaining information about the Model from your previous get Method.

Add `ModelState.Clear()` before your ForEach statement and

also comment out this code or else your textbox fields will be blank

```
//account.Username = string.Empty;
```

Comment: Why would that be the case though?

Comment: The clear should be before the foreach loop in order to retain the error messages generated.

Comment: Yea good catch travis, also comment out where you are setting UserName to empty string or else you will get blank textboxes

Comment: My original intention was to return empty inputs, but I think you're right.  It's more intuitive if they return the username with the error.